# Datatable sorting but group rows

Tags: javascript, datatables

I want to enable sorting but group multiples row into one in the same time. So that they will always sorted by in groups. Like row of group 1 will stick with group 1 and so on..

http://live.datatables.net/wuwaxiqe/1/edit

Answer (score 6):

Use [`orderFixed`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/orderFixed) option to always apply ordering to a certain column before/after any other columns.

For example:

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
   "orderFixed": {
      "pre": [ 2, 'asc' ]
   }        
});
```

See [updated example](http://live.datatables.net/wuwaxiqe/3/edit) for code and demonstration.